# app crashes when opening intent in new activity error nullexception?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am pretty new to all this, but I am quite stuck with something that I just cant figure out. I looked through numerous previously asked questions, but to no avail. I am trying to pass a value over from a listview to a new activity. I am using intents, the selected values do get registered just fine going out (checked it with a simple textview within my mainactivity and a log. However when i want to retrieve them in my new activity the app crashes. So I guess it has to problem is somewhere in my second activity. Help is much appreciated. (ps. my code probably needs to clearing up, but Ill get to that afterwards.)
My main_activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    EditText logedit;
    EditText logexistedit;
    Button logbutton;
    Button logexistbutton;
    ListView lognaamlist;
    ArrayAdapter userArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logedit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.logedit);
        logbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logbutton);
        logbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        lognaamlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        logexistbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.existlogbutton);
        logexistbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        lognaamlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);


       userArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_loginrow, R.id.loginnaam,
                userList);
        LoadPreferences();

        lognaamlist.setAdapter(userArrayAdapter);
        lognaamlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       }

    protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    protected void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String dataSet = data.getString("LISTS", "None Available");
        userArrayAdapter.add(dataSet);
        userArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

        private void actienaam(String String) {
        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://packagename.firebaseio.com/lijstapp");


       String savename = (((logedit.getText().toString())));
       Firebase userRef = ref.child("users");
        Map<String, Object> rec1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        rec1.put(savename, savename);
        userRef.updateChildren(rec1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.logbutton:
                actienaam(((logedit.getText().toString())));
                // Also add that value to the list shown in the ListView
                userList.add(logedit.getText().toString());
                userArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SavePreferences("LISTS", (logedit.getText().toString()));
                break;

            case R.id.existlogbutton:

                userList.add(logedit.getText().toString());
                userArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SavePreferences("LISTS", (logedit.getText().toString()));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

     String userdata = (String) userList.get(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Keuzelijstactivity.class);

        i.putExtra("userdata", userdata);
        startActivity(i);

        // Log the item's position and contents
        // to the console in Debug
        //later veranderen in volgende stap
        Log.d("omg android", position + ": " + userList.get(position));
    }}
```

My second activity:

```
  public class Keuzelijstactivity extends Activity {
    TextView boodschaptext;
    TextView takentext;
    TextView test;
    String userdata;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boodschaptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boodschappenlijst);
        takentext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.takenlijst);
        test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
        setContentView(R.layout.lijsten_layout);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

       Intent i = getIntent();
      userdata= i.getStringExtra("userdata");
      test.setText(userdata);
    }
```

And finally my logcat when crashingl:

```
01-26 22:21:13.205      834-834/prolijst.rob.com.prolijst E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{prolijst.rob.com.prolijst/prolijst.rob.com.prolijst.Keuzelijstactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at prolijst.rob.com.prolijst.Keuzelijstactivity.onCreate(Keuzelijstactivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your error is on line 30 of `Keuzelijstactivity.onCreate(Keuzelijstactivity.java:30)`. Which line is that?

Comment: The line piyush mentioned, but I couldnt figure out what was wrong with it, untill now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
boodschaptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boodschappenlijst);
takentext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.takenlijst);
test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
setContentView(R.layout.lijsten_layout);
```

You have initialized your views before calling  `setContentView(R.layout.lijsten_layout);` thats why you are getting NPE exception. So just change it with

```
 setContentView(R.layout.lijsten_layout);
 boodschaptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boodschappenlijst);
 takentext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.takenlijst);
 test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
```

Comment: Thx it worked :). I didnt expect the order to matter much. Tried basically everything...except this.